# Any shortcut to installing wine dependencies?

Tags: wine, 19.10

I am trying to install wine-stable-i386=5.0.0~eoan with `sudo apt-get install wine-stable-i386=5.0.0~eoan`, but when I do this, there are a ton of dependencies. Is there any way that I can automatically install all or do I have to install them one by one?